# aws rds multi-az configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

On aws rds postgresql (not aurora) cluster, there is a writer instance and a reader instance. Couple of questions -

1. In the describe-db-cluster command output it shows "MultiAZ": true, but describe-db-instances of this cluster's instances says "MultiAZ": false.

- (a) Are the cluster's instances configured to be multi-az?
- (b) Whenever writer instance fails over I see reader becomes writer, a bit confused here because I thought the difference between multi-az and read replica setup is that in case of multi-az's automatic failover happens and in case of read replica's failover needs to be triggered manually. How is it that read replica is becoming primary in case of failover?
- (c) Why multi-az shows to be true at cluster level. Is it
  showing multi-az because of reader and writer being in different
  az's?

2. How do I know what storage class (provisioned iops, gp2) is being used by the cluster's instances? I am unable to figure it out from the describe-db-instances or describe-db-cluster command output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some **confusion** here what is cluster, aurora, multi-az, and so on.

"Cluster" only applies to Aurora. Thus there is no such thing as "postgresql (not aurora) cluster" and command `describe-db-cluster` will not work on non-aurora databases. If you try to run it on non-aurora db instance you will get:

```
DBCluster <name> not found
```

In Aurora, `MultiAZ` is provided through **Aurora replicas** (i.e. readers), while in RDS databases, `MultiAZ` is provided through a **Stand-by** db instance, which is different from read-replicas.

> How is it that read replica is becoming primary in case of failover?

Because this is exactly what happens when you run Aurora. In RDS, the Stand-by becomes the new primary, not read-replica.

> Why multi-az shows to be true at cluster level. Is it showing multi-az because of reader and writer being in different az's?

Yes. In aurora Multi-AZ is enabled through readers in different AZs than primary.

> How do I know what storage class (provisioned iops, gp2) is being used by the cluster's instances?

In Aurora there is no such notion as different storage classes. AWS uses different and **in-house develop** storage solution for it.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, makes much more sense now. Just a follow-up question - since aurora implements multi-az via read replicas, if I want upgrade instance class - does it first upgrade read replica and then fails over and then upgrades instance class on new read replica? I am looking to upgrade 7tb db from 8xlarge to 16xlarge with one reader and write in the aurora cluster. How much time would it take?